# selección dinamica

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Buen día, quería hacer la siguiente consulta porque estoy realizando un tablero en Power bi y realice lo siguiente, en el menú Modelado -> Parámetro nuevo -> Campos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se creo lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual ese parametro lo puse en un filtro y si selecciono Volumen me trae el siguiente resultado en una tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si selecciono Dolares me trae el siguiente resultado en una tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesitaría es que al momento de seleccionar Volumen solo me muestre esas 3 columna y me oculte una

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando selecciono Dolares me muestre

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya muchas gracias